# PR from release to main has conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow, merge-conflict-resolution

Very recently we moved over to a "Git Flow" approach, where we make use of `develop`, `release`, and `main` branches. Recently we created a `main` branch from the same commit as the most recent `release` branch. Every time we merge a `release` branch into `main`, we then merge `main` into `develop`, usually with a new branch off of `main` where we resolve conflicts first (since they're protected branches).

However, with the newest `release` branch created off of `develop`, we have conflicts between `release` (which is just `develop` at this point) and `main`. Resolving these conflicts is just a 0 file change PR, but I don't understand why there are even conflicts in the first place. I've drawn the most recent history to try further demonstrate the process:

[image: Git process]

**Note that all of those merges are squashed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using standard [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), you should *never* have merge conflicts when merging `release` into `main`/`master`. If you do have conflicts, something is wrong. The reason conflicts shouldn't exist is because the only two ways for commits to appear on `main` are from the `release` branch, or a `hotfix`. In the case of a `hotfix` merging into `main`, immediately afterwards you should merge `main` back into `release` if a release branch exists, and if it doesn't, you should merge `main` back into `develop`. This way `release` will always be ahead of `main`.

With standard Git Flow, the only time you should ever potentially have conflicts are when merging:

- `main` back into `release` (hotfix conflicts with release)
- `main` back into `develop` (release/hotfix conflicts with develop)
- `release` back into `develop` (release conflicts with develop)

If you are having conflicts merging `release` into `main`, the most likely reason is you have a hotfix on `main` that didn't get merged back into `release` immediately afterwards, and skipping this step is potentially dangerous because if you deploy the release branch to production directly, you won't have those hotfix changes in it.

Regarding this text in your diagram:

> At some point, trying to merge *develop into main* results in merge conflicts.

I assume you meant "merge `main` into `develop`" rather than the other way around, since there isn't actually a flow of `develop` directly into `main`. It's perfectly normal to have conflicts when merging `main` down into `develop`, which typically happens when the same files are modified on both `develop` and the `release` branch after it branches off. That's just a normal course of development unless you are willing to implement code freezes.

**Process Problem:**

> Note that all of those merges are squashed

This doesn't seem right. That's definitely not part of Git Flow, and in general you never want to rewrite commits on long-lived/protected branches. That means commits on `develop`, `release`, `hotfix`, and `main`/`master` should not be squashed. The only time it *might* make sense to use squash with Git Flow would be when merging feature branches into `develop` or `release`, if you don't care about the specific commit information on the feature branches.

Side Note regarding this statement:

> Every time we merge a release branch into main, we **then merge main into develop**, usually with a new branch off of main where we resolve conflicts first (since they're protected branches).

This is a minor point, but bravo for merging `main` back into `develop` after merging `release` into `main`. Standard Git Flow suggests actually merging the `release` down into `develop` instead of doing it from `main` there, however, it doesn't make a difference from a code standpoint, and doing it the way you're doing it is IMHO cleaner and slightly more efficient in the long run. It's one of the few tweaks I always recommend to the Standard Git Flow.